# Willing to take them along with

Tags: usage

I think the following sentence is not correctly framed **(The highlighted part)**

> Jannayak Janta Party leader Dushyant Chautala on Friday said his party was ready to support any political party in the State willing to **take them along with the Common Minimum Programme**. He said that 75% reservation in jobs to the youth in Haryana and increase in old age pension were on top of the party’s agenda.

[Link](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/jjp-leader-dushyant-says-ready-to-support-any-party-with-cmp/article29800128.ece/amp/)

Because **take somebody along** is the correct construction, why are they using **with**?

Comment: You haven't provided any link to the source. Are you ***sure*** there isn't a comma after ***willing to take them***? Even if there isn't, that might be just poor proofreading. Is the text intelligible to you if you assume there ***should*** be a comma there?

Comment: What is the alternative to using *with*? "*Take them along … (?) … the Common Minimum Programme.*" What else could go there other than *with*? It has the same function as *I'm eating **with** my family tonight* or *I'll have a hamburger **with** fries.* or *I'll take bad **with** the good.*

Comment: Put a comma after “them” to see where the clause is probably intended to end. It’s an ugly construction but possibly being quoted from a spoken comment where the phrasing and pauses, lost in this version, may have aided comprehension.

Comment: I'm fairly certain "take them along" is being used as an idiom to mean the verb "help", ie "any...party willing to help them with". It's unlikely any party would announce their support for "anyone willing to take them". Much more likely they will give support to "anyone willing to help the programme".

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is understandable if you read it as giving two conditions for supporting a politicial party.

> ... his party was ready to support any political party in the State [that was (1)] willing to take them [and (2) also willing to take the] Common Minimum Programme.

I assume that the "Common Minimum Program" is an important policy that is supported by the Jannayak Janta Party.

This meaning can be clarified by the use a comma. You can consider the missing comma to be a mistake in the orginal.

> his party was ready to support any political party in the State willing to take them, along with the Common Minimum Programme.

Answer (score 0):

I think "take them along with" means "help them move forward with". So "the party is willing to support anyone who helps them (enact their programme)" would be a good summary. To many English speakers this would sound unusual, but it does make some logical sense to use this as an idiom for help, eg "i will cheer for any progress that takes me along with it". Such a sentence should be easily understood by English speakers.